# jquery calendar

Tags: jquery, calendar

I recently received a mockup that calls for two linked calendars, and I was wondering if anyone had a starting point for how I might accomplish this using jquery.  The calendar on the left is a simple datepicker from jquery ui, but I don't know where to start with the one on the right, much less how I might link them. Any ideas? Thanks folks!

[www.jontakiff.com/calendar/calendar.html](http://jontakiff.com/calendar/calendar.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are several jQuery plugins which generate a complete calendar like the Google Calendar. For example, [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) is one of them.

On the jQuery website you can find a [list of calendar plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/event-calendar) (actually it's a list of plugins tagged with calendar, but it still holds).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what you want:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

You can use `.fullCalendar( 'changeView', viewName )` to change the view to week mode on startup.  And `.fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', year [, month, [ date ]] )` to set the date when you click on a calendar date on the small calendar.

You can use the `header` property to add or remove buttons for the other calendar views (if you only want week view).

Answer (score 0):

I am, not sure of what the second calendar is, but this is how those two can be linked.

```
$('.cal').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      // set the date of the second calendar to this date.
   }
});
```